# Problema Land/Layout Port/Layout

Tags: android-layout

Tengo un problema con el cambio entre el Land/Layout y Port/Layout. Cuando giro el dispositivo, siempre se queda el diseño en Port/Layout.
En Androidmanifest.xml tengo colocado:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
```

Y he creado en mi activity:

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
```

Aquí cargo un RecilerView según la orientación. Pero me falta como hacer que me cambie de un Layout a otro. Los Layouts están creados en AndroidStudio como land/main.xml y port/main.xml.